# Analytics Data Import - Read & Analyse

Tags: google-analytics

I was reading the Analytics documentation and saw that a user with Read & Analyse permissions can access the Data Import functionality, however when I try to access it under an account with these permissions I either receive "Permission Denied" or no content appears.

I was just wondering if anyone else has the same thing?

Comment: Are you able to access other components of the GA API with the same login?

Answer (score 0):

[Actually the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015078?hl=en) says

> You must have Edit permission at the property level to upload data or
>   delete uploaded files. You can see uploaded data files if you have
>   Read & Analyze permission.

So with read&analyze permissions you can use the data in reports, but you cannot upload data or manage data uploads. For that you need edit permissions.